# Prove $2^a|2$ (is even) and that $3^b|3$ (is odd)

Tags: proof-writing, divisibility, proof-explanation, parity

I know this seems like an easy proof, but I cant seem to directly prove it even though I know it's true.  I need to prove that $2^a$ is even, and $3^b$ is odd, so I'm trying to prove that $2^a|2$, meaning that it is even, and $3^b|3$, meaning that it is odd.

I have that $2^a|2$ means that $2^a=m2$ for some integer $m$. I know that the definition of any even number $n$ is $n=2k$ for some integer $k$.

I have that $3^b|3$ means that $3^b=m3$ for some integer $m$. I know that the definition of any odd number $n$ is $n=2k+1$ for some integer $k$.

I am in desperate need of some direction, and I'm trying to be very precise and only use definitions as opposed to just stating that $2^a$ is even because OF COURSE it's even.  Thank you!

Addition: So now i can see how I can prove $2^a$ is even. How can I prove $3^b$ is odd then? Although I can now prove that it is a multiple of $3$, this won't help to show that it is odd I see now. How could I prove that $3^b$ is odd?

Comment: The correct way to write "$a$ divides $b$" is $a \mid b$; you've written it the other way round. You want $2 \mid 2^a$, and so on.

Comment: $3$ divides $6$, and $6$ is not odd.

Comment: ok, so now i can see how I can prove 2^a is even.  how can I prove 3^b is odd then? since proving it can be a multiple of 3 is not sufficient for it being odd.

Comment: When you multiply two odd numbers what kind of answer do you get? Odd or even? What if you multiply a whole bunch of odd numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^a = 2^{a-1} \color{red}{\times 2}$ which is manifestly even because it's explicitly $\color{red}{\text{a multiple of $2$}}$. (This holds unless $a=0$, of course, but then $2^a$ isn't even.)

To show that $3^b$ is odd, consider $$3^b = (2+1)^b = 2^b + \binom{b}{1} 2^{b-1} 1^1 + \binom{b}{2} 2^{b-2} 1^2 + \dots + \binom{b}{b-1} 2^1 1^{b-1} + \binom{b}{b} 1$$
which is $$2^b + \binom{b}{1} 2^{b-1} + \binom{b}{2} 2^{b-2} + \dots + \binom{b}{b-1} 2^1 + 1$$
which is $$2 \times \left[2^{b-1} + \binom{b}{1} 2^{b-2} + \binom{b}{2} 2^{b-3} + \dots + \binom{b}{b-1}\right] + 1$$
which is one more than a multiple of $2$.

Comment: Thank you so much!  So now i can see how I can prove 2^a is even. how can I prove 3^b is odd then? Although I can now prove that it is a multiple of 3, this won't help to show that it is odd I see now. How could I prove that 3^b is odd?

Comment: Oh, my bad; I misread your question, and thought you asked why $3^b$ was divisible by $3$. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful and looks so clean.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, let's write $3^n,n\geq1$.
Use the mathematical induction:

For $n=1\Rightarrow3^1=3$ is odd.

Assuming for $n=k\Rightarrow 3^k$ is odd, we will prove for $n=k+1$:

$3^{k+1}=3\cdot3^k=odd\cdot odd=odd$.